# Enforce unique tuples in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any built-in function in jQuery or JS that enforce uniqueness of tuples in HTML table?

Comment: Can you give us an example of a situation where you would want this function to catch?

Comment: Let say we have some text fields through which user is adding data into table but we want to enforce that user should not add duplicate rows. I know it can be done by iterating table each time before inserting a row but I am curious is there any buildin function which provide us this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: http://www.datatables.net/examples/

There are many built-in functions in it, If you find any difficulty then let me know.